# What RxJs operators to use for a persistent Spinner with an initial delay?

Tags: rxjs

Trying to learn and use RxJS at the same time which is proving pretty gnarly!

Here are my requirements - I have a Spinner component, and starting from when its `isLoading` prop is set to `true`:

- if `isLoading` is set to `false` before `initialDelay`, it never shows
- if `isLoading` is set to `false` after `initialDelay` but before `minSpinTime`, it persists for `minSpinTime` and then disappears
- if `isLoading` is set to `false` after `initialDelay` and after `minSpinTime`, it shows and then disappears synchronously with `isLoading`

To implement this, I have a `Subject` which gets passed a boolean based on my UI. However I want to apply some operators to the `Subject` but am totally lost on what operators to use. This is what I have right now (the subscribe code uses React but that's not relevant here):

```
subject
  .audit(
    (val: boolean) =>
      val ? Rx.Observable.interval(initialDelay) : Rx.Observable.interval(0)
  )
  // doesnt work, false is merely delayed, i want it synchronous
  .audit(
    (val: boolean) =>
      val ? Rx.Observable.interval(0) : Rx.Observable.interval(minSpinTime)
  )
  // this also doesnt work, false goes thru too fast
  // .switchMap(
  //   (val: boolean) =>
  //     val
  //       ? Rx.Observable.of(true)
  //       : Rx.Observable.of(false).throttleTime(minSpinTime) //auditTime also doesnt work here
  // )
  .subscribe((val: boolean) => this.setState({ show: val }));
```

I feel I need to consult more experienced RxJS folk. please help! I think i may need to combine 2 or more observables to achieve the desired effect. I know that i need at least one of those observables to start after the first one, so that suggests using switchMap?

EDIT 1: here is a half-working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/72k9qko211 but it doesnt fulfil the "disappears synchronously" requirement of the 3rd spec

EDIT 2 : I actually have a fully working example of this component: http://tsiq-ui-components.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?knob-isLoading=true&knob-initialDelay=3000&knob-minSpinTime=3000&selectedKind=Components%2FIcons&selectedStory=3000ms%20SmartSpinner&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs but it's implemented with @DavidKPiano's `xstate` and I am trying to convert it to use `RxJS` - but you can see that it conforms to all 3 cases in the spec (toggle isLoading). hope the communication is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two different `Subject`s since there is a relationship between triggering the loading/not-loading, and the delayed streams that emit the loading state.

Basically, I did two streams that delay with some amount, and aborts if the other Subject is triggered before the delay.

The `zip` operator is used to make sure that deactivation happens when both the deactivateLoaderSubject is called, and both minimal delay have passed.

`SwitchLatest` will keep the outer streams alive, while the inner streams only emit max once.

The only thing this solution doesn't take into account is if you want to emit from `deactivateLoaderStream` right away if it's *before*
 the `initialDelay`. I couldn't figure out why that would be an issue, so went with the easiest solution I could manage.

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mq380ol5nj

At the moment of posting this answer, the code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Rx from "rxjs";

const initialDelay = 1000;
const minSpinTime = 1000;

const activateLoaderSubject = new Rx.Subject();
const deactivateLoaderSubject = new Rx.Subject();

const activateLoaderStream = activateLoaderSubject.switchMap(() =>
  Rx.Observable.of(null)
    .delay(initialDelay)
    .takeUntil(deactivateLoaderSubject)
);

const deactivateLoaderStream = activateLoaderSubject.switchMap(() =>
  Rx.Observable.zip(
    Rx.Observable.of(null)
      .delay(initialDelay + minSpinTime)
      .takeUntil(activateLoaderSubject),
    deactivateLoaderSubject
  ).take(1)
);

const initialState = { loading: null };

const activateLoaderReducerStream = activateLoaderStream.map(() => state => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true
}));

const deactivateLoaderReducerStream = deactivateLoaderStream.map(
  () => state => ({ ...state, loading: false })
);

const stateStream = Rx.Observable.merge(
  activateLoaderReducerStream,
  deactivateLoaderReducerStream
)
  .startWith(initialState)
  .scan((state, reducer) => reducer(state));

stateStream.forEach(state => {
  render(
    <div>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
});

// Removes loader directly when deactivate is triggered
const finnishVeryLate = () => {
  activateLoaderSubject.next();

  setTimeout(() => {
    deactivateLoaderSubject.next();
  }, initialDelay + minSpinTime + 1000);
};

// Shows loader for minSpinTime
const finnishLate = () => {
  activateLoaderSubject.next();

  setTimeout(() => {
    deactivateLoaderSubject.next();
  }, initialDelay + 1);
};

// Doesn't show loader
const finnishEarly = () => {
  activateLoaderSubject.next();

  setTimeout(() => {
    deactivateLoaderSubject.next();
  }, initialDelay - 1);
};
```

Comment: hey thank you so much for doing this!! i put a react wrapper around it to test it intuitively and here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/72k9qko211 i think still fails the 3rd case where its supposed to disappear synchronously with `isLoading`. in my testing it seems to wait before disappearing even after `initialDelay + minSpinTime` has elapsed.

Comment: I haven't spent enough time testing if it works. If not, I will look at coding a more testable solution like your own component sandbox.

Comment: I updated the codesandbox with the structure I prefer, but it is the same logic as posted here in more files and with a React view.

Comment: this is far and away the best stackoverflow/twitter experience ive had. closing as solved! thank you